# Help me find a replacement vent

Tags: vent, chimney

Have a wood burning fireplace and the chimney has an air intake vent.  The vent has seen better days but not sure what to ask for at the local stores. See photo

[ update ] 
After getting up in the attic to see where this vent connects to, it does in fact seem to be a fresh air intake for the woodburning fireplace.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Any idea what this vent is for, or where it connects? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

That's an outside air intake.  It's purpose is to allow air in but keep critters and debris from entering.  They make these specifically for this purpose but a common use is to take a DRYER vent that has a screen, remove the flapper (which would prevent air from entering) and use that as the intake.

You should find either at your local home supply store.

Comment: Yep. It's probably a 4" duct.

Comment: But dryer vents usually don't have screens. They'd clog up almost immediately.

Comment: I guess you haven't looked at dryer vents lately.  Most have screens to prevent critters from getting in.

Comment: Its not the dryer, as that is on the other side of the house.

Answer (score 0):

This might work out good:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B078SR74L3/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078SR74L3)

It is stainless steel and has a screen. I used one for kitchen range exhaust.